# storing an jpg image from internet to disk / db

Tags: iphone, sqlite, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-data

I don't know which is the most efficient way of organizing images downloaded from server. I will be downloading around 200 images on to my iPhone on request for download. Which is the most efficient way of organizing ? just dropping it as a file on the phone's memory or having it in sqlite (via coredata) after download ? which one is most efficient and easy to handle ? which access is faster ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule of thumb is to put them (or any bigger binary data) onto disk directly, and if the whole app organizes its data with a database / CoreData, then put the paths of the images in there.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK , Iphone has minimum 8GB of memory. That will be enough for images. Also It depends upon the frequency of image downloads. If you download 200images daily then u need some application that will push it in your sqlite db. Advantage of this will be your all image files will be inside a single db. No scattered images. But if you want to store only 200 images then i would recommend it store on your phone memory with some image managing tool like ACDSEE in windows, that will help you viewing images in slide show or what ever manner you want.